# Latex Table of content format

Tags: latex

How to achieve such two numbering styles in latex ?  Like this figure.
[image]

Comment: Please make a [mre]. Looks pretty much like a default toc....

Comment: This may depend on the `\documentclass`. Please [edit] your question and add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch the two numbering styles using `\pagenumbering`: With `roman` you get the letters, and with `arabic` the numbers. Just set it to roman first and then switch to arabic when the real sections start, like in this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}

\newpage
\section*{Acknowlegement}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowlegement}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\newpage
\section{Introduction}

\newpage
\section{Literature}

\end{document}
```

With this table of contents in the output:

[image: TOC]